# React not reading 'userData' in ternary operator

Tags: reactjs, api, async-await, axios, conditional-operator

I am using React trying to pull data from an api that gives me a random user's info. I need to return 'No user' if userData == null and the user's name and email if it's not. I'm trying to use a ternary operator to solve this but React keeps wanting me to spread userData. If I do that it then proceeds to tell me that userData is not defined. I am new to React and not sure what to do about this. Can someone give me some insight on this? Here is my code

```js
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import './App.css'
import UserSummary from './UserSummary.jsx'

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchUser() {
      const currentUser = `https://api.randomuser.me/`
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(currentUser)
        console.log(res.data)
        setUser(res.data)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
    fetchUser()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Who's That User?</h1>
      <UserSummary 
        userData={'currentUser'} 
        {userData === null ? <h3>There is no user</h3> : <h3>{userData.name, userData.email}</h3>}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```js
import {useState} from 'react'
import React from 'react'

function UserSummary(props) {
   const {userData} = props
   return (
      <div></div>
   )
}

export default UserSummary
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, `userData` *is* undefined, your state variable is called `user`.  And then you do `userData={'currentUser'}` which sets the `userData` prop in that component to the *string* "currentUser" - If you initialize it to null, and then set it to the response you get (assuming the response is something like `{ name: '', email: '' }`, and actually pass that variable, then it should work.  Something like this:

```js
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import './App.css'
import UserSummary from './UserSummary.jsx'

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchUser() {
      const currentUser = `https://api.randomuser.me/`
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(currentUser)
        console.log(res.data)
        setUser(res.data)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
    fetchUser()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Who's That User?</h1>
      <UserSummary 
        userData={user} 
        {user === null ? <h3>There is no user</h3> : <h3>{user.name, user.email}</h3>}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```js
import {useState} from 'react'
import React from 'react'

function UserSummary(props) {
   const {name, email} = props
   return (
      <div></div>
   )
}

export default UserSummary
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing wrong props to UserSummary Component.

it should be like this

```
function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchUser() {
      const currentUser = `https://api.randomuser.me/`
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(currentUser)
        console.log(res.data)
        setUser(res.data)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
    fetchUser()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Who's That User?</h1>
      <UserSummary 
        userData={'currentUser'}
        isUserValid={Boolean(userData.length)} 
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


import { useState } from "react"
import React from "react"

function UserSummary(props) {
    const { userData, isUserValid } = props
    return (<div>
        {!isUserValid && (

            "User is not present"
        )}

        {isUserValid && (

            <h3> user.email </h3>
            <h3> {user.name} </h3>
        )}
        </div>)

export default UserSummary
```